# Set LinearLayout Orientation using references instead of layout-land (only xml)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml, android-resources

I have a layout which is used on both landscape and portrait. I have it in `/layout` and `/layout-land` folders. The only difference is the `android:orientation`.

I would like to have only 1 xml in `/layout` because it is easier to maintain. I'd like to use `/values` and `/values-land` instead. Is this possible?

What I have now is (unnecessary code removed):

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

vs

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

I though about something like:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="@xxxx/linear_orientation"/>
```

As an ultimate solution I also thought about creating a custom style only for this `LinearLayout` (I don't like this solution, but will have to use it if I can't fine another option).

Note: I know it is possible to do it on `java`, but I'm looking for a **xml-only** solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I would like to have only 1 xml in /layout because it is easier to
>   maintain. I'd like to use /values and /values-land instead. Is this
>   possible?

Yes, it's possible. You can use Style to achieve that.

The Style in the styles.xml under /values:

> ```
> <style name="LinearLayoutOrientation" >
>     <item name="android:orientation">vertical</item>
> </style>
> ```

The Style in the styles.xml under /values-land:

> ```
> <style name="LinearLayoutOrientation" >
>     <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
> </style>
> ```

Your final xml code for LinearLayout:

```
 <LinearLayout 
    style="@style/LinearLayoutOrientation"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, that is my ultimate solution. I was hoping not to create a custom style for only 1 attribute. It just doesn't sound good.

Comment: @gian1200 Sorry, I did't read your question carefully. I don't know other solution except java to achieve this.